# Clickable grid instead of editable

Tags: cobol

I have a grid with screen settings like this:

```
02 SCR-KUN-LST-1.
    03 SCR-KUN-LISTE GRID PAGED SIZE 145 LINES 21 3-D
        LINE 1 COL 1,25 FONT SMALL-FONT
        RECORD-DATA        = KUN-LISTE-LINJE
        DATA-COLUMNS    = (1 11 12 62 112 142 157 172 187 237 252)
        DISPLAY-COLUMNS = (1 10 12 40 65 86 99 112 125 135)
        ALIGNMENT = ("L","C","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L")
        ROW-DIVIDERS       = (1,1)
        COLUMN-DIVIDERS    = (1,1)
        DIVIDER-COLOR      = 32 
        CURSOR-COLOR       = 80
        HEADING-MENU-POPUP 63
        HEADING-COLOR      = 256
        CURSOR-FRAME-WIDTH = -1
        NUM-ROWS           = 0
        VPADDING           = 50
        VIRTUAL-WIDTH      = 155
        VSCROLL ADJUSTABLE-COLUMNS USE-TAB 
        BOXED BORDER-COLOR BLACK
        REORDERING-COLUMNS SORTABLE-COLUMNS
        COLUMN-HEADINGS CENTERED-HEADINGS TILED-HEADINGS
        POP-UP MENU KUN-MENU     
        ID IS 209 BEFORE PROCEDURE IS VIS-KOMMENTAR 
        EVENT PROCEDURE KUN-LISTE-SAVE
        EXCEPTION PROCEDURE KUN-LISTE-EVENTS.
```

When running the grid, it is loaded with the columns etc., but when I click/double click it comes in a editor mode. I want the grid to handle double click as a function to open a line instead.

Anyone have an idea of what I can do to do that? Let me know if you need more code to see it better.

Comment: you made something clickable in COBOL? that's actually interesting. what software are using to achieve that? who ever knows the answer will probably need to know that

Comment: @SaggingRufus It's ACUCOBOL-GT.

Comment: Microfocus has great support from what I have heard contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `ENTRY-REASON` special property on `GRID` elements.

https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/acucorpproducts/docs/v6_online_doc/gtman2/gt2546.htm

> ENTRY-REASON (alphanumeric)
>
> This property records the user's action that caused the grid to shift
>   to entry mode. It is set immediately before the MSG-BEGIN-ENTRY event
>   is generated, and it is retained until overwritten by another
>   MSG-BEGIN-ENTRY event or until the grid is destroyed.
>
> The encoding is a single PIC X character as follows:
>
> **x"00"**
>   A X"00" (binary 0, ASCII null) value indicates that the user
>   double-clicked on the cell
>
> **x"0D"**
>   A X"0D" (binary 13, ASCII
>   carriage-return) value indicates that the user pressed the  key
>   Otherwise      Any other value is the key that the user pressed. For
>   example, if the user started typing "John," then the letter "J" is
>   returned by ENTRY-REASON.
>
> ENTRY-REASON can be only inquired. Setting it has no effect. You may
>   inquire on ENTRY-REASON during a MSG-BEGIN-ENTRY event to determine
>   what caused the current entry to start. Note that you can then
>   prohibit entry if you desire by moving EVENT-ACTION-FAIL to
>   EVENT-ACTION and returning from the event procedure.

Given that, and your given code, your `KUN-LISTE-SAVE` paragraph could have

```
KUN-LISTE-SAVE.
    EVALUATE EVENT-TYPE
       WHEN MSG-BEGIN-ENTRY
          INQUIRE SCR-KUN-LISTE ENTRY-REASON = YOUR-ENTRY-REASON
          IF YOUR-ENTRY-REASON = X"00"
            PERFORM YOUR-ON-DBL-CLICK
          END-IF
    END-EVALUATE.
```